# Write on a network folder from android (Xamarin) System.UnauthorizedAccessException

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, directory

I created a android app to create a stockage list by capturing code bars, the idea is to write a `csv` file in to a network folder, because I want the app to run as much offline as it's possible.

Currently my code looks like:

```
        string path = Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath;
        string filename = Path.Combine(path, "stock.csv");
        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(filename, true))
        using (var writer = new CsvWriter(streamWriter))
        {
            foreach (var item in articulos)
            {
                writer.WriteField(item.codbar);
                writer.WriteField(item.reference);
                writer.WriteField(item.quantity);
                writer.NextRecord();
            }
        }
        string path2 = @"\\Desktop-jce8pl5\csv\stock.csv";
        File.Copy(filename, path2,true);
```

But I keep geting a System.UnauthorizedAccessException

- I tried to enter directly to the file from another computer and there
  is no problem.
- I give full permission to "all" and "network"
- I tried directly with IP I tried not to copy, just to create

  ```
      string path = @"\\Desktop-jce8pl5\csv\stock.csv";
      FileStream fs = null;
      if (File.Exists(path))
      {
          fs = File.Open(path, FileMode.Append);
      }
      else
      {
          fs = File.Create(path);
      }
  ```

But there is no way. 
Any help?
Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried from your Android device via a samba enabled file explorer (like ES File Ex)? Can you connect and browse your Windows shares? Rooted phone? Then use `cifsmanager` to mount those shares on your 'Droid so local apps can R/W.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, as a first aproach we discover that windows 10 was blocking anonymous conections, so I change the option. Then I start with the cifsmanager but on that moment we decided that, if the user has access to local network he will most sure have acces to internet, so I will send the file by email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @RobertN sugested, I tried to connect with EX File Ex and detected that I was unable to, so I checked the windows 10 general configuration to shared folders and it was only enabled to auth users.
I changed that, then I start with the cifsmanager but on that moment we decided that, if the user has access to local network he will most sure have acces to internet, so I will send the file by email.